# How to add the OS X flavor to a Qt app

Tags: c++, macos, qt5

I have used Qt previously only in the form of PyQt, and today I tried the *original* version of Qt in C++.

I got it working, however, when if start up my app, I have several problems with it:

- it's stationary, which means, I cannot drag it across the screen
- I cannot change the size of the window
- it does not have a OS X type status bar (which contains the three colored buttons and the name of the window)

How can I add these features to my C++ Qt app?

[image: QtApp]

I have tried to look for a solution, but only found `QtApplication::setStyle();`, which did not solve my problem.

You can see the code [here](https://gist.github.com/henrikgiesel/0e58a09836f9c63efe9e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code inside your subclass of QMainWindow contains this line:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

That is probably causing most of the problems you describe.  Try removing that line.

Comment: Wow, that was stupid. I copied that line from somewhere else. Thanks a lot.